# Getting syntax error on sql database create table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

So i'm trying to create a table using MySQL Workbench like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS document_categories;

CREATE TABLE document_categories (
   id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
   updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
   deleted_at datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

But im getting this error:

> 11:54:19  ​ CREATE TABLE document_categories (   id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),   updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),   deleted_at datetime DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (id) )    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '​ CREATE TABLE document_categories (   id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_IN...' at line 1    0.000 sec

I don't really see what the problem is here. Also I'm using MariaDB as the database

Comment: Sounds like a Workbench bug. What happens if you execute the query directly in the CLI?

Comment: @Strawberry seems to be right ^^ this appears to be an error caused by workbench. The creation of the table succeeded in my terminal. So maybe just use a terminal ?

Comment: I actually found out that the problem was a whitespace thing, when I copy/paste the code, it doesn't work, but when i write it from start to finish it works fine